# How to access customer upload file using media url?

Tags: magento2

I have created a customer attribute called the customer logo and I want to get URL of that customer logo in the Email I am trying to access using but it gives 404

https://localhost/pub/media/customer/A/P/demo.png

So is there any way like we can get the proper URL of the customer upload file? and that's direct accessible everywhere like a display in email etc

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="routename">
            <module name="Vendorname_Modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Block/Logo.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

Class Logo extends Template {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
     */
    protected $viewFileUrl;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $viewFileUrl
     * @param array $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $viewFileUrl,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->viewFileUrl = $viewFileUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Get Customer From Session
     */
    public function getCustomer() {
        if($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()){
            $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
        }else{
            $customer = null;
        }
        return $customer;
    }

    /**
     * Get Customer Logo Url
     */
    public function getCustomerLogoUrl() {
        if($this->getCustomer() != null){
            $customer = $this->getCustomer();
            if(!empty($customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_logo'))){
                $customerLogoUrl = $this->getUrl('routename/logo/view/', ['image' => base64_encode($customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_logo')->getValue())]);
            }else{
                $customerLogoUrl = $this->viewFileUrl->getUrl('Vendorname_Modulename::images/default-logo.png');
            }
        }else{
            $customerLogoUrl = null;
        }

        return $customerLogoUrl;
    }

}
```

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Controller/Logo/View.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Logo;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface
     */
    protected $urlDecoder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface $urlDecoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface $urlDecoder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultRawFactory    = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->urlDecoder  = $urlDecoder;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * View action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $file = null;
        $plain = false;
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('file')) {
            // download file
            $file = $this->urlDecoder->decode(
                $this->getRequest()->getParam('file')
            );
        } elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('image')) {
            // show plain image
            $file = $this->urlDecoder->decode(
                $this->getRequest()->getParam('image')
            );
            $plain = true;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem */
        $filesystem = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
        $directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $fileName = CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER . '/' . ltrim($file, '/');
        $path = $directory->getAbsolutePath($fileName);

        if (!$directory->isFile($fileName)
            && !$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage')->processStorageFile($path)
        ) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }

        if ($plain) {
            $extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            switch (strtolower($extension)) {
                case 'gif':
                    $contentType = 'image/gif';
                    break;
                case 'jpg':
                    $contentType = 'image/jpeg';
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $contentType = 'image/png';
                    break;
                default:
                    $contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
                    break;
            }
            $stat = $directory->stat($fileName);
            $contentLength = $stat['size'];
            $contentModify = $stat['mtime'];

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
            $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
            $resultRaw->setHttpResponseCode(200)
                ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
                ->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType, true)
                ->setHeader('Content-Length', $contentLength)
                ->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r', $contentModify));
            $resultRaw->setContents($directory->readFile($fileName));
            return $resultRaw;
        } else {
            $name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            $this->fileFactory->create(
                $name,
                ['type' => 'filename', 'value' => $fileName],
                DirectoryList::MEDIA
            );
        }
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Logo" name="customer_logo" template="Vendorname_Modulename::account/logo.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/account/logo.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset info">
    <div class="field customer_logo">
        <label for="customer_logo" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Logo') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="file" name="customer_logo" id="customer_logo" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Logo') ?>" class="input-text validate-filesize validate-fileextensions-image" data-validate="{required:false}" data-role="customer_logo">
            <?php 
                $customerLogoUrl = !empty($block->getCustomerLogoUrl()) ? $block->getCustomerLogoUrl() : '';
                if(!empty($customerLogoUrl)){
            ?>
                    <div class="file-preview">
                        <a class="preview-link preview-image" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $customerLogoUrl; ?>">
                            <img tabindex="0" src="<?php echo $customerLogoUrl; ?>" alt="" height="90px" width="90px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
            <?php   
                } 
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function ($) {

    $.validator.addMethod('validate-filesize', function (v, elm) {
        var maxSize = 5 * 102400;
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            if (elm.value) {
                var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var e = oas.getFile(elm.value);
                var size = e.size;
            }
        } else {
            if (elm.files[0] != undefined) {
                size = elm.files[0].size;
            }
        }
        if (size != undefined && size > maxSize) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, $.mage.__('The file size should not exceed 5MB'));


    $.validator.addMethod('validate-fileextensions-image', function (v, elm) {
        var extensions = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'];
        if (!v) {
            return true;
        }
        with (elm) {
            var ext = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                if (ext == extensions[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }, $.mage.__('Disallowed file type.'));
});
</script>
```